# How to go live with Core Data Heavyweight migrations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an existing project, that is currently in the App Store, which contains 6 versions of core data models. On version 7 I require a heavy weight migration, after creating a mapping model a realized that when I try to simulate migration from v3 to v7 it always fails. As I understood from docs and from this very site I have to create mapping model for every possible migration scenario.
What if I go live, and after some time I will create v8 of model, I will need to create all possible mapping models for migration to v8?

I did not find docs to answer this question.

Just in case, here is how I load persistent store

```
let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
storeDescription.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
storeDescription.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
storeDescription.shouldAddStoreAsynchronously = false

loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
    FatalError("Failed to load store with error: \(error)")
}
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: This is a great question. Yes, CoreData requires you to implement migration path for every version by default, but there's a way to avoid version mayhem: progressive migration, which doesn't come built-in. See https://kean.blog/post/core-data-progressive-migrations https://williamboles.me/progressive-core-data-migration/  for example

Comment: @KirilS. That was really helpful! Thank you!